# How to find an index of given String in array of strings?

Tags: java, string, equality

Surely the solution to this is the following:

```
public long myFunc(String name) throws Exception {
    for(int i=0;i<amount;i++){ 
       if(this.otherString[i].equals(name)) 
           return longArray[i]; 
    } 
    throw new Exception("Not found"); 
}
```

However, this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Why does it not seem to be the case?

Comment: Its gets to the //string not found area

Comment: This code looks 100% correct. The truth is somewhere else. Case sensitivity maybe?

Comment: I've run it through a debugger and they are the same at one point but return is not executed.

Comment: If you can produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, we can help work out what is going on. Until that point, unfortunately, we really can't.

Comment: Could you add in the complete code?

Comment: Please clarify whether you're looking for a substring (an occurrence) or the whole string. Also, please note that the `equals` method is case sensitive.

Comment: Whole string occurrence

Comment: Sorry for the ugliness^. Its a bit more complex than first said but still the same principles.

Comment: What is `amount`? Try using `otherString.length` to make sure you go through the whole array

Comment: amount covers enough of the array so that the strings are equal. Also, updated original post for clarity

Comment: Find methods typically don’t throw exceptions, if an item is not found. I recommend returning a constant that indicates not found, e.g., `-1`. Moreover, this method appears to be doing two different things. I recommend returning only the found index from `myFunc` and accessing the `longArray` from the caller to keep a proper separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out '\u0000' was at the end of the string that was meant to be equal. This does not show in printing. Next time I will be more ruthless in the inspection of the debugging. Thank you for all the suggestions though, and sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Guava, then your code can looks like this

```
String[] stringArray = {"s1", "s2", "s3"};

int index = Iterators.indexOf(Iterators.forArray(stringArray), new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String input) {
        return input.equals("s2");
    }
});
```

or simpler

```
int index = Arrays.asList(stringArray).indexOf("s2");
```

Your code can also look like this

```
public class Finder {

    private String[] stringArray = {"s1", "s2", "s3"};

    public int findIndex(String name) {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
            if (stringArray[i].equals(name))
                return i;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException("Not found");
    }

    public static void main(String... s) {
        int index = new Finder().findIndex("s1");

        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the original post. Although, your method works, that's not really the point. It's more a matter of why doesnt the my method work

Comment: @MatthewFrost I see that your post has changed a little bit. So I modify a little bit my answer. I instead of `amount` uses `this.otherString.length` and instead of `return longArray[i]` uses `return i`.

Comment: What does the "or simpler" return if it cant find "s2"? (-1 sorry )

Comment: @MatthewFrost Return -1. In JavaDoc you can read `Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element.`.

Comment: Thank you. But this still doesn't work for my code. I'll have to look further.

Comment: @MatthewFrost Your code doesn't work because you must delete `amount ` and `longArray` and instead of that put other value. Or maybe you can copy your all code here?

Answer (score 0):

You can either run your code through a debugger and find out why it doesn't work, or add some println traces to your original code and you'll see what the problem is:

```
public long myFunc(String name) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Looking for: " + name);
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++){
        if(this.otherString[i].equals(name))
            return longArray[i];
        System.out.printf("%4d: \"%s\": No match.%n", i, this.otherString[i]);
    }
    for (int i = amount; i < this.otherString.length; i++)
        System.out.printf("%4d: \"%s\": Not checked.%n", i, this.otherString[i]);
    throw new Exception("Not found");
}
```

By the way, make sure you are correctly interpreting the method's behaviour. Could it be that it's finding it but throwing an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException because `i` is greater than longArray.length, and you misinterpret that as the exception you are explicitly throwing?

Comment: And what results did you get when you did this?

Comment: As expected they all say no match/not checked

Comment: So are you saying there is a string between otherString[0] and otherString[amount-1] that equals 'name', and yet the method still prints "No match"?

Comment: As strange as it sounds yes. I have gone through it with a debugger, and the strings do match at one point, but the code within the if statement never executes.

Answer (score -2):

This might be completely wrong, but isn't the problem just missing curly brackets in the if statement? I am new to the java language and the example is probably messy, but it uses the same structure from your question and works just fine:

```
public class random_class {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] a = new String[] {"hi!", "hello world!", "ho ho ho world!"};       
    int b = getHWIndex(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}

public static int getHWIndex(String[] stringArray){
    int i;
    Boolean test = false;
    for(i=0;i<stringArray.length;i++){
        if(stringArray[i].equals("hello world!")){
            test = true;  
            break;
        }
    }
    if(test == true){
    return i;}else{
        return i = 0; // this is not a good answer... 
//but as you return an int I could not think on a quick way to fix   the return when there is no match.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No Java supports 1 line with no curly braces